# Multi Transaction Manager Spring Configuration with Annotations

Tags: spring, jpa, annotations, spring-transactions

There are two bean JpaTransactionManager.

Can Manage them with Qualifier notation.

```
<bean id="transactionManagerConstant" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="constant"/>

    <qualifier value="first"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerRelative" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="relative"/>
    <qualifier value="second"/>
</bean>
```

Java code:

```
@Transactional("first")
public String saveWork(){

    em1.persist(work);
    work = (Work) ctx.getBean("work");
    return "/workLists.xhtml";
}

@Transactional("second")
public String saveEvent(){

    em2.persist(event);
    event = (Event) ctx.getBean("event");

    return "/eventLists.xhtml";
}
```

The problem is: how do I use the level of isolation or readOnly assignment? @Qualifier annotations does not work:

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
@Qualifier("first")
public String saveWork(){

    em1.persist(work);
    work = (Work) ctx.getBean("work");
    return "/workLists.xhtml";
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
@Qualifier("second")
public String saveEvent(){

    em2.persist(event);
    event = (Event) ctx.getBean("event");

    return "/eventLists.xhtml";
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should be putting the `@Qualifier` annotation on the member that is the `TransactionManager`, not on the method that uses it.

The following assumes that `em1` and `em2` are the `TransactionManager`'s defined in the spring configuration above.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("first")
private TransactionManager em1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("second")
private TransactionManager em2;

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public String saveWork(){

    em1.persist(work);
    work = (Work) ctx.getBean("work");
    return "/workLists.xhtml";
}

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public String saveEvent(){

    em2.persist(event);
    event = (Event) ctx.getBean("event");

    return "/eventLists.xhtml";
}
```

Comment: Hi nicholas. This is TransactionManager object, javax.transaction.TransactionManager object? The persist operation is done with this object?